Password not working
I use Cntl-AlT- T to install an update or a new program and I am asked for a password.  I attempted to use the password I used when iI installed Ubuntu 24.04 and it will not accept it.  What can I do after I use "sudo" and nothing happens?

When you type a password in the terminal, the cursor does not move. There is no ********. This is normal in Ubuntu and all other Linux. Just enter your password and hit the Enter key.

This question is similar to: Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
